# Win32 API logic error: Code compiles fine but the main window doesn't show up

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm rewriting a software I wrote, because of program size and performance problems; The code compiles fine but the window doesn't show up.

I've looked into other questions about this but none solved my problem, that's why I'm asking a new question, for sake of completeness, please explain what is wrong with the code and how to solve the problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.
Here's the code:

**WFrame.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wchar.h>

class WFrame
{
public:
    WFrame();
    WFrame(LPCWSTR szClassName, LPCWSTR szWindowTitle, HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow, int nX, int nY, int nWidth, int nHeight, DWORD dwStyle = WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    ~WFrame();

    void show();

    static LRESULT CALLBACK staticWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
protected:

private:
    HWND hWnd;
    int cmdShow;
};
```

**WFrame.cpp**

```
#include "WFrame.h"


WFrame::WFrame()
{

}

WFrame::WFrame(LPCWSTR szClassName, LPCWSTR szWindowTitle, HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow, int nX, int nY, int nWidth, int nHeight, DWORD dwStyle)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon = NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm = NULL;
    wClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WFrame::staticWindowProcedure;
    wClass.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL,
            L"Window class creation failed",
            L"Window Class Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    this->hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szClassName,
        szWindowTitle,
        dwStyle,
        nX,
        nY,
        nWidth,
        nHeight,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        int nResult = GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,
            L"Window creation failed",
            L"Window Creation Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

}

WFrame::~WFrame()
{
    delete this;
}

void WFrame::show()
{
    ShowWindow(this->hWnd, this->cmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(this->hWnd);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WFrame::staticWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WFrame* winptr = (WFrame*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if (winptr == NULL) {
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else {
        return winptr->WindowProcedure(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WFrame::WindowProcedure(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(this->hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            if (!GetParent(this->hWnd))
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(this->hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "WFrame.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WFrame * frame = new WFrame(L"Window", L"Window", hInstance, nCmdShow, 0, 0, 1024, 700);
    frame->show();

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Thanks to further answers.

Comment: What is the value of `this->cmdShow`?

Comment: cmdShow is the value sent to the WinMain function when the program starts, it may vary depending on your settings for the program, but, in this case, I just checked and it's 10.

Comment: I was trying to point you to what @chishui said in their answer. :/

Comment: You don't need to put in `delete this` You don't need `delete->` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see you assign a value to member variable cmdShow, so its default value is 0, which is SW_HIDE, so you should try the code below, see if the window can show up or assign cmdShow in WFrame initializer.

```
void WFrame::show()
{
    ShowWindow(this->hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(this->hWnd);
}
```

Comment: I just noticed, he also does not call `SetWindowLongPtr`, so `WFrame::WindowProcedure` will never be used. I compiled the code and fixed to mistake you found and it worked. Just as a sidenote though, the value of `cmdShow` does not default to `0`. It is undefined.

Comment: Thank you :D I was not setting the this->cmdShow value, so now it's working, your answer is also very valuable @BetaCarotin , thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` for the `dwStyle` param of `CreateWindow`. This flag should actually be used for the `dwExStyle` param of `CreateWindowEx`. Use `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` instead.

Don't forget to `delete frame;` when you're done. You actually don't even need a pointer here. Just instantiate `frame` on the stack.

Also, you should `return 0;` for the window messages that you handled, instead of calling `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: _@Beta Carotin_ /OT how many carrots a day does it take to keep your eyes focussing that sharp? You're notable!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Quite a few, but I substitute with coffee ;)

Comment: What about using a recognizable avatar: http://cdn.blogs.sheknows.com/vegan.sheknows.com/2012/04/Rabbit-eating-carrot.jpg? Coffee is quite a bad substitute for carrots, don't take me too serious ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's actually really adorable. I like it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I made the changes that you proposed, but the window still doesn't show up, any idea?